# matching string which does not end in predefined part(s)

Tags: java, regex

given string "abcdefgh" how do I match all strings starting with "abcde", whose do not end in "fgh"?

More generic task - match string startin with certain **common** pattern but do not end in any of pre-defined (exclusion) patterns.

```
"\babcde(^fgh)\b"
```

doesn't work

Comment: Negative lookahead should solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the needed prefix and the excluded suffix may not overlap, you can use a negative lookahead. By "strings", I assume you mean "words":

```
"\babcde(?!\w*fgh\b)"
```

If the prefix and suffix may overlap, move the lookahead to the front

```
"\b(?!\w*fgh\b)abcde"
```

If by "strings" you mean "strings", use the `^` and `$` as the boundary conditions:

```
"^(?!.*fgh$)abcde"
```

If you want to get the match as well, rather than just test the string, include "the rest of the string" to the regex:

```
"^(?!.*fgh$)abcde.*$"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex:

```
^foo(?!.*bar$).*$
```

to match all string that begin with `foo` but do not end in `bar`.

The part `^foo` ensures that the string begins with `foo` and

The part `(?!.*bar$)` is the negative lookahead assertion to ensure the string does not end in `bar`.

[**See it**](http://www.rubular.com/r/OFZbl6gJe1)